# Simple Kivy Gestures (swipes)

Tags: kivy

The Kivy [gesture documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.gesture.html) is a bit lacking and refers only to the gesture example.

I was wondering why Kivy does not provide any helper methods like `on_swipe_left`, `on_swipe_up` etc. Preferably taking minscore as an argument.

Why does one have to manually create a database with base64 encoded strings instead of having the framework handle this automatically? And is there a library that does such a thing already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy: Swiping (Carousel & ScreenManager)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934445/kivy-swiping-carousel-screenmanager)

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `kivy-examples/gestures/my_gestures.py` and `gesture_board.py`, you can see an example on how to manage any gesture you want. Simply generate the text equivalent of your drawing, and store it in `my_gestures.py`, and you can then detect any similar gesture.