# How to swipe left and right in python kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to add a swipe event in my kivy app and in my knowledge kivy does not have an event such as `on_touch_left` or `on_touch_right` available but it have another `on_touch_move` function which I think can be used for this purpose

```
class TestWidget(BoxLayout):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print touch.x
```

What I noticed in the above code is that if we swipe towards right `touch.x` value increases and if we swipe right `touch.x` value decreases. We just have to take the difference between the first and last `touch.x` value to predict left/right swipe.

The problem is how to store and retrive `touch.x` values from the initial to final.

Comment: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934445/kivy-swiping-carousel-screenmanager) is similar and may help you.

Comment: The accepted answer have to import gesture module and I prefer not to go that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `on_touch_move` event, you can use `on_touch_down` and save `touch.x` then use `on_touch_up` and compare `touch.x`, for example:

```
initial = 0
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    initial = touch.x

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if touch.x > initial:
        # do something
    elif touch.x < initial:
        # do other thing
    else: 
        # what happens if there is no move
```

A better way is to compare using `if touch.x - initial > some-value` to set a minimum swipe range to do some action.

Comment: Thats an awesome answer, I didnt thought of that, thank you. Because I am using this inside a class there was a minor problem with `initial` which has to be `self.initial` inside functions. I also took your last advice and I made it as percentage instead of difference and it works amazing

Comment: Yeah I missed the `self.initial` part, but I'm glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I use *on_touch_down* along with the *touch.dx* and *touch.dy* properties to calculate this. The reason being that I need to dynamically calculate the length of the swipe, as it determines the alpha of an image. For non-dynamic calculations, I find Moe A's solution more straightforward and less resource-intensive.

```
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.enabled:
            self.x_total += touch.dx
            self.y_total += touch.dy

            if abs(self.x_total) > abs(self.y_total):
                "do something"
            else:
                "do something else"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def on_touch_move(self,touch):
    if touch.dx > 0:
        self.ids.scrn_mnger.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.ids.scrn_mnger.current = 'scrn_open'
    elif touch.dx < 0:
        self.ids.scrn_mnger.transition.direction = 'left'
        self.ids.scrn_mnger.current = 'scrn_media'
```

Comment: Please consider adding comments to your answer to help OP and others understand how it solves the OP's problem.